# Linear regression involving angles in a triangle.

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares

> In a survey experiment, three independent measurements $29.5^{\circ}$, $30.5^{\circ}$,
>   $120.5^{\circ}$ are obtained from the three angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of a triangle. Formulate the appropriate linear model, and find the least squares estimates $\hat{\alpha},
> \hat{\beta},\hat{\gamma}$ of the respective angles.

I'm not quite sure how to represent this. What I had done was say that
$$180 = \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \varepsilon$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the error term. Then, the sum of squares of errors, $SS$, is simply
$$SS= (180-\alpha-\beta-\gamma)^2.$$
Differentiating with respect the each of the parameters, setting the equation to $0$, and thus dividing out $-2$, we get the normal equations as
\begin{align*}
&\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(180-\alpha-\beta-\gamma)\alpha = 0 \\
(180-\alpha-\beta-\gamma)\beta = 0 \\
(180-\alpha-\beta-\gamma)\gamma = 0
\end{array}
\right. \\[0.25cm]
\implies
&\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\hat{\alpha} = 180-\hat{\beta}-\hat{\gamma} \\
\hat{\beta} = 180-\hat{\alpha}-\hat{\gamma} \\
\hat{\gamma} = 180-\hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta} \\
\end{array}
\right. .
\end{align*}
This seems to make intuitive sense, but is it right? I'm just not sure if I set up the model correctly. There is, then, 1 observation, but 3 parameters. A subsequent question asks to calculate an unbiased estimator for the variance. How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

I wonder if the problem is not to minimize $$SS=(\hat{\alpha}-\alpha)^2+
(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^2+(\hat{\gamma}-\gamma)^2$$ subject to the condition $\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}+\hat{\gamma}=180$.

If this is the case, extract $\hat{\gamma}=180-\hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta}$ from the constraint to get $$SS=(\hat{\alpha}-\alpha)^2+
(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^2+(180-\hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta}-\gamma)^2$$ Compute $SS'_{\hat\alpha}$ and $SS'_{\hat\beta}$ and set them equal to zero. This will give you two linear equations for two unknowns  $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$.

Comment: Hmm, okay I see where you are coming from there. But wouldn't we need to then compute the partials with respect to $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ as opposed to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, since the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given measurements from the experiment?

Comment: Yes for sure ! Sorry for the typo's. I fix it.